# iOS iPhone physical screen size in millimeters

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there a way to obtain iPhone physical screen size in millimeters in iOS?

The only information available is PPI for each iPhone model and screen size in pixels but not in millimeters.

Comment: Just out od curiosity - why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Swift CGSize extension allowing to retrieve iPhone physical screen size in millimeters with regard to the current device:

> Note: it supports only iPhone X and older models.

```
extension CGSize {
    /**
    * Physical device screen size in millimeters
    */
    static func physicalDeviceScreenSize() -> CGSize? {
        guard let ppi = deviceModelNameToPpiMapping[UIDevice().modelName], ppi != 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        let width = (UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width * 25.4) / ppi
        let height = (UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height * 25.4) / ppi

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    static private var deviceModelNameToPpiMapping: Dictionary<String, CGFloat> {
        // PPI values derived from https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions
        return [
            "iPhone10,3": 458.0, // iPhone X
            "iPhone10,6": 458.0, // iPhone X
            "iPhone11,2": 458.0, // iPhone Xs
            "iPhone11,4": 458.0, // iPhone Xs Max
            "iPhone11,6": 458.0, // iPhone Xs Max
            "iPhone11,8": 326.0, // iPhone Xr
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this an extension of CGSize and not something more appropriate like UIDevice?

Comment: or an extension of UIScreen

Comment: hi @viktor how did you derived the `deviceModelNameToPpiMapping` values? thank you!

Comment: @mikey from https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions